# Dockerizing an existing Project

Tags: docker

I have a web based application using Play framework and Scala which I would like to Dockerize. Essentially, I would like to do the following:

1. Create a docker file that would be my docker container for the play application
2. Be able to pass in a configuration to this docker file so that I can build the docker image either for my local code base or pull from master branch

Any suggestions on how do I get started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, no real need to create a new Dockerfile when thankfully many existing ones already exist for this purpose.

By quickly searching on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=play%20framework&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&starCount=0&pullCount=0) these [[1](https://hub.docker.com/r/dordoka/play-framework/), [2](https://hub.docker.com/r/ingensi/play-framework/)] images for the Play Framework already exist. You can use these "as is" or simply base a new image on them if for some reason you want more additional functionality.

`docker pull <image name>` and `docker run <image name>` suffice to get them up and running, with [plenty of parameters](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) according to your needs

Whatever your choice may be, it's probably a good idea to first familiarize yourself with the concepts of Docker by reading the [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/) (which are written nicely).

Additionally, to address your configuration requirements, focus specifically on [volumes in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/), which allow you to share a folder from your host with your container.